# Using make-symbol, boundp and symbol-value to reference a variable who's name is made from a string

Tags: variables, symbols

When I run the following three lines with `eval-region`

```lisp
(defcustom custom-var "some-custom-value" "for testing only")
(setq indirectRef (make-symbol "custom-var"))
(message "ref=%s, is bound=%s" indirectRef (boundp indirectRef))
```

the output is

```
`ref=custom-var, is bound=nil`
```

Why does `boundp` not return `t`?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're mixing up a few things.

- Your `(defcustom...)` is essentially irrelevant to the rest, except that it sets the value of variable `custom-var` to a given string.
- You need to `C-h f make-symbol` and `C-h f intern`. And see (elisp) [**Creating Symbols**](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Symbols.html).

---

> `make-symbol` is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> `(make-symbol NAME)`
>
> Return a newly allocated uninterned symbol whose name is `NAME`.
>
> Its value is void, and its function definition and property list are nil.

---

> `intern` is a built-in function in ‘C source code’.
>
> `(intern STRING &optional OBARRAY)`
>
> Return the canonical symbol whose name is `STRING`.
>
> If there is none, one is created by this function and returned.
>
> A second optional argument specifies the obarray to use;
> it defaults to the value of `obarray`.

```lisp
(boundp 'custom-var)                ; => t, since you did the `defcustom`.
(boundp (intern "custom-var"))      ; => t, since `intern` returns the same symbol.
(boundp (make-symbol "custom-var")) ; => nil. `make-symbol` returns an uninterned symbol.
```

More succinctly:

```lisp
(eq (intern "custom-var") (make-symbol "custom-var"))      ; => nil.
(eq (make-symbol "custom-var") (make-symbol "custom-var")) ; => nil.
(eq (intern "custom-var") (intern "custom-var"))           ; => t.
```